# How to Redefine Meta Key to Use Esc Key Only and Allow Using Alt Key for Another Purpose

Tags: key-bindings

I am using ubuntu 18.04. The Esc-v scrolls up by a page as expected (classical Emacs command with Esc being the meta key). But I want to use Alt-v as a "paste command". In other words: can I decouple the Alt key from Esc key so that Esc remains as the meta key but the Alt key is used for other stuff?

Comment: Please edit your question title to make it more informative of what you want to do.

Comment: You can do the opposite, i.e. making escape not act like meta, with `(define-key local-function-key-map (kbd "<escape>") nil)`.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs wants to make the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key equivalent to the *Meta* modifier.  This actually is fine with your goal, which is to fre the *Alt* modifer.  All you need to do is to stop Emacs's "remapping" of the *Alt* modifier, which it does when it sees that there's no Meta modifier.  Details will vary depending on your system, but for me:

```
xmodmap -e 'remove mod1 = Meta_L'
xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Meta_L'
```

makes convinces Emacs that I have a *Meta* modifier, and from then on, Emacw will not treat my <kbd>Alt</kbd> key as the *Meta* modifier but as the *Alt* modifier, so `Alt-x` turns into `A-x` rather than `M-x`.

Of course, you can also arrange to have both *Alt* and *Meta* modifier keys (e.g. by remapping the left and the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys differently, e.g. one to `Alt_L` and the other to `Meta_R`).

Comment: Should this appear in my .emacs file. When I put it in my .emacs file, I get an error when loading it. I also tried putting it in a file called .Xmodmap in my home directory. Does not seem to work

Comment: No, these are commands to execute in a shell, e.g. a command line or a file like `~/.xsession`.

Answer (score -1):

Both the alt key and the esc key are setting the "Meta" modifier on the key.

Differentiating them without v significant collateral damage by breaking other meta binding is going to be difficult.

The easiest change to achieve what you desire might be to rebind something else to the `scroll-down-command` (which is what `M-v` is bound to by default).

A good option might be to define `C-c v` to `scroll-down-command`

From the manual:

> Sequences consisting of `C-c` and a letter (either upper or lower case) are 
>   reserved for users; they are the only sequences reserved for users, so do not 
>   block them.